# Is this set $\{(x\overline{y},|x|^2)\,;\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2,\;|y|=1\}$ convex?

Tags: complex-numbers, convex-analysis

Let the following subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$

$$F=\left\{(x\overline{y},|x|^2)\,;\;(x,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2,\;\text{and}\;|y|=1 \right\}.$$

> Is $F$ a convex subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Comment: Hint: Begin by noting that $F$ has the simpler form $F=\{(z,|z|^2):z\in\Bbb C\}$.

Comment: I don't see why $F$ is equal to the new set? In the new set there is only one parameter. The new set is equal to $C\times R_+$

Comment: [Sigh...] What?  Say $F'$ is the new set. Then $(2,2)\in\Bbb C\times\Bbb R_+\setminus F'$.

Comment: @Schüler consider the polar form of a complex number to see why $|x\overline{y}|^2 = |x|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $F$ is not convex. This is clear if we say $$F'=\{(z,|z|^2):z\in\Bbb C\}$$and note that

> > $F'=F$.

Proof: Say $p\in F$. Then $p=(x\overline y,|x|^2)$ where $|y|=1$; hence if we set $z=x\overline y$ then $p=(z,|z|^2)$, so $p\in F'$.

Conversely, say $p\in F'$, so $p=(z,|z|^2)$. If $x=z,y=1$ then $p=(x\overline y,|x|^2)$, so  $p\in F$.